# How do I check all checkboxes on a page using webdriver?

Tags: css-selectors, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to check/uncheck  all checkboxes present in page.
Code snippet is as following:-

```
@Test
public void checkBoxAll() {

    List<WebElement> checkBoxList=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input [type='checkbox']"));
    for(WebElement checkBox:checkBoxList)
    {
        checkBox.click();   
    }
    List<WebElement> unCheckedBoxList=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input:not(:checked)[type='checkbox']"));
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(unCheckedBoxList))
        Assert.fail();

}
```

First I find out all check boxes using **("input [type='checkbox']")**.Then click them in loop and then find all check boxes which are checked(for test case to be executed successfully there should be none).
     I tried some approaches from google,but ain't working for me.Please tell me what I am doing wrong being a novice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what was problem in what I was doing earlier or the solution proposed above,but both didn't work.I tried out different things and below is the working solution.***id='first'*** is id  of div under which all checkboxes are placed.

```
@Test
public void CheckBoxAll() {
    String cssSelectorForNotCheck=("[id='first'] input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)");
    List<WebElement> checkBoxList=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorForNotCheck));
    for(WebElement checkBox:checkBoxList)
    {
        checkBox.click(); 

    }
    checkBoxList=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorForNotCheck));
    if(!checkBoxList.isEmpty()) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is:

```
// Find all checked checkboxes with xpath
List<WebElement> checkBoxList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @checked='checked']"));
        for(WebElement checkBox:checkBoxList)
        {
            checkBox.click(); 
        }

// Assert if any checkbox left checked
List<WebElement> allCheckedBoxList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @checked='checked']"));
    if(!allCheckedBoxList.isEmpty()) {
        Assert.fail();
    }
```

**Update**
If you need to look for unchecked checkboxes use following xpath instead:

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and not(@checked='checked')]
```

Comment: It should work for you, I am using exatly this snippet in our TestCase. Where lies the problem? It just does not work for you or are you becomming some runtime exception? Is ist possible that checking a checkbox is triggering submit or page reload?

Comment: Yes it was not working for me.Element couldn't be selected.I am not an expert of css but can say that possible reason could be how html was implemented.